# Identify image blurred or not in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using `paperclip` to upload images in my rails application

Gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Now I want to check the quality of image
For exa: image is blurred or not, image qaulity is low or image clicked while covering the camera lence

Is this possible in rails?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible in Ruby. Rails is just a web framework.
If you are asking if Ruby or Rails or paperclip have something like

`Image.first.blurred?`

then unfortunately not. I would guess that no programming language or framework has this specific functionality build in.
But since we are software developers we can utilize tons of library's so our app is obeying to everything that we want to achieve. But first we have to teach them.

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) would be a nice library for such functionality. Its used in tons of usecases when visual analyses is required. There is also a [wrapper](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv) in ruby for it.

Sure for your use case you have to to build some small library for it. [Here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/) you have an example in python which sure be easily translated to ruby. When you got this working you even could implement some Model extension to enable

`SomeObject.blurred?`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will check and try to implement it.
And Yes you are correct I mean same ruby on rails, sorry my wordings are little bit wrong.